# Broken string on windows search screen

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

I am developing a python application to send some images via whatsapp but when I try to attach the image the word is broken, does anyone know what happens?

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
AbreAnexo = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[data-icon="clip"]')
AbreAnexo.click()
AbreImagem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[class="Ijb1Q"]')
AbreImagem.click()
pyautogui.typewrite("C:\\Users\\f_teicar\\Documents\\Lanchonete\\001-Cardapio.png",interval=0.02)
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Expected is to write *C:\Users\f_teicar\Documents\Lanchonete\001-Cardapio.png* 
but output is it *car\Documents\Lanchonete\001-Cardapio.png*

Comment: Just a guess, but try putting time.sleep(2) right before the pyautogui.typewrite (you will need to import time)

Comment: Excellent. I have a better way to wait for a page which I'll add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially on external web sites, it takes a while for the page to load. This means that the next step (or part of it) might be ignored as the page isn't ready to receive further operations from the Selenium client.

time.sleep(n) where n is the number of seconds to wait, is a quick way of waiting for the page to load, but if it takes a bit longer than the time you specify, it will fail, and if it loads much faster, then it will waste time. So I use a function to wait for the page like this.

```
@contextmanager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import staleness_of
from contextlib import contextmanager

def wait_for_page_load(timeout=MAX_WAIT):
    """ Wait for a new page that isn't the old page 
    """
    old_page = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
    yield
    webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(staleness_of(old_page))
```

To call the function, use something like

```
with self.wait_for_page_load():
    AbreImagem.click()
```

where the second line is anything that causes a new page to load. Note that this procedure depends on the presence of the  tag in the old page, which is usually pretty reliable.